# Disable another module from my module xml

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I've a Magento 1.9 shop where a 3rd party module in interfering with my own module. I need to disable the 3rd party module, but due to too-long-to-explain-here reasons I cannot just edit its .xml and set it to `<active>false</active>`: I actually need to **disable said 3rd party module from my own**.

I thought I would be easy form my `app/etc/modules/Mymodule.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>

        <Mycompany_Mymodule>

            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>

            <depends>
                <3rdparty_Moduletodisable />
            </depends>

        </Mycompany_Mymodule>

        <3rdparty_Moduletodisable>
            <active>false</active>
        </3rdparty_Moduletodisable>

    </modules>
</config>
```

But this doesn't work: my module gets loaded, but the other one doesn't get disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: After Making those changes are you deleting the var/ folder.

Comment: Deleting `var/` would destroy the shop. You supposedly meant `var/cache/`: yes, did that, no effect.